# Get dropdown variable in JS returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have form with a textfield, a dropdown menu, some radiobuttons and a textarea.
everything works fine except the dropdown menu.
Here is it:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="employee" size="1" class="text" value="">
                                <option value="1" selected="selected">Heino</option>
                                <option value="2">Michael Jackson</option>
                                <option value="3">Tom Waits</option>
                                <option value="4">Nina Hagen</option>
                                <option value="5">Marianne Rosenberg</option>
                            </select> 
<button id="send" class="btn">Send</button>
```

If i click the button my JS gets every value but the dropdown shows `undefined`

```
    $('#send').click(function() {

    var result=true;

    var name = $('input[name=name]');
    var employee = $('input[name=employee)';
    var product = $('input[name=product]:checked');
    var knowledge = $('input[name=knowledge]:checked');
    var message = $('textarea[name=message]');

    // Data
    var data = 'name=' + name.val() +
    '&employee=' + employee.val() +
    '&product=' + product.val() +
    '&knowledge=' + knowledge.val() +
    '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message.val());
```

product and knowledge are radiobuttons. they work. name and message also.

Is there a way like the "checked" for the radio buttons?
this script should show a little success message if the formular was send successfully as an email.

Comment: There is a typo when you set employee, your ' is in the wrong place. The select has no name attribute either, so using the name selector wouldnt work. `var employee = $("#employee").val()` would work better.

Comment: It says still "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First think, you forget closing *]* bracket. second, you search for input where dropdown is select element. Third, you didn't add *name* attribute to dropdown element.

Change this code:

```
$('input[name=employee)';
```

into

```
$("#employee");
```

or

```
$('select[id=employee]');
```

Correction:

Sorry, try this

```
$('#employee').find(":selected").text();
```

http://jsbin.com/fihizupoko/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks. The missing bracket was an translation mistake. But it still doesn´t work with your solutions. After hitting the submit dutton my browser opens a blank page with my php file in the url..

Comment: Try my correction above. If you need value, try to use this $('#employee').find(":selected").val()

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys.
Got the answer with your help!

Changed the dropdown to:

```
<select style="width:341.5px" class="dropdown" name="employee" id="employee" size="1" class="text" value="">
                            <option value="Heino" selected="selected">Heino</option>
                            <option value="Michael Jackson">Michael Jackson</option>
                            <option value="Tom Waits">Tom Waits</option>
                            <option value="Nina Hagen">Nina Hagen</option>
                            <option value="Marianne Rosenberg">Marianne Rosenberg</option>
                        </select>
```

(Names in the value field)

an the JS to:

```
var employee = $('select[name=employee]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
var employee = $('input[name=employee)';
```

`)` in ' '

Change at :

```
var employee = $('input[name=employee]');
```